# Subquery returned more than 1 value how to handle it

Tags: sql

My SQL Query is

```
  select ID, ModuleID,
         (SELECT ((CAmount * CPercentage)/100)  FROM Table1 ) as Percentage 
    from Table1 
order by ModuleID ;
```

It works perfectly if there is only one value but if there is more than one value i get an error. how to handle it, i want all the amount in the table to be converted to its corresponding percentage please help.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: what are you actually *trying to do* ? Your question tells us how you are trying to do it, but not what you are attempting to achieve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
SELECT TOP 1 ((CAmount * CPercentage)/100)  FROM Table1
```

But that depends on your intensions...

Answer (score 0):

Or...

```
  select ID, ModuleID,
         (SELECT ((SUM(CAmount) * SUM(CPercentage))/100)  FROM Table1 ) as Percentage 
    from Table1 
order by ModuleID ;
```

That will successfully handle multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me as slightly strange that your subquery is using the same table as the main query. It looks like you are trying to get the percentage for each module, so getting the percentage for the whole table might be the wrong result.

Unless I'm misunderstanding your intention, I would expect this to be the correct query:

```
SELECT ID, ModuleID, SUM((CAmount * CPercentage)/100) AS Percentage 
FROM Table1 
ORDER BY ModuleID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the value for each record, you don't need a subquery at all:

```
select ID, ModuleID, (CAmount * CPercentage) / 100 as Percentage 
from Table1
order by ModuleID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use This split with ","

(SELECT distinct
        DocumentList=stuff((SELECT distinct (', '+CCD2.document_filename + ' ' )
        from callcenter_documents CCD2
        WHERE document_answerid =AnswerID
        for XML path('')),1,2,'') from  callcenter_documents CCD1
        WHERE document_answerid =AnswerID) AS document_filename